# Как вытащить пароли с Google Chrome используя Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, безопасность

Хотелось бы создать приложение которое вытащит пароли с Google Chrome которые лежат тут 
C:\Users\elnur\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: Уверен, что `Google` не хранит пароли в легкодоступном формате

Comment: Это так. Для поиска пароля рекомендую лопатить исходники Chromium. А вот если поступать разумно - я бы использовал приложение- аналог LostPass и в ус не дул. в крайнем случае для него парсер написать недолго

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Я не думаю, что изучение исходников поможет. Там скорее всего не будет очевидной дыры security through obscurity - там будет какая-никакая криптография.

Comment: @A K там скорее всего пароль шифруется ключом, полученном из данных железа (если ничего не поменялось). А значит зная данные железа и алгоритмы можем дешифровать

Comment: И да - это бестолковое занятиеэ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел код который делает это в питоне очень легко. Если кому нужен

```
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
import csv
import json
import argparse
import win32crypt

def main():
    info_list = []
    path = getpath()    
    connection = sqlite3.connect(path + "Login Data")
    with connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            v = cursor.execute(
            'SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
            for origin_url, username, password in v.fetchall():
                if os.name == 'nt':
                    password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)[1]
                    info_list.append({
                        'origin_url': origin_url,
                        'username': username,
                        'password':password
                    })

    return info_list
def getpath():
    if os.name == "nt":
        PathName = os.getenv('localappdata') + \
        '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\'
    return PathName

file = open("testfile.txt","w")

for i in main():
    file.write(str(i)+"\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Это для хромиума или старого хрома?
Вроде шифрование должно быть, не?

Comment: Для обычного Google Chrome.  password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)[1]